# How can I make this refers to the class in the function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, webrtc

Usually when we use `this`, it refers to the class.

But in this case, `this` is `dataChannel`, how can I let `this` refers to `VideoService` again? Thanks

```
export class VideoService {
    dataChannel:any;

    setupPeerConnection() {
        this.dataChannel.onopen = this.dataChannelStateChanged;
    }

    dataChannelStateChanged() {
        // here this = dataChannel, how can I let this = VideoService
        console.log(this); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind context explicitly with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
export class VideoService {
    dataChannel:any;

    setupPeerConnection() {
        this.dataChannel.onopen = this.dataChannelStateChanged.bind(this);
    }

    dataChannelStateChanged() {
        console.log(this); 
    }
}
```

or use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve lexical scope:

```
export class VideoService {
    dataChannel:any;

    setupPeerConnection() {
        this.dataChannel.onopen = () => this.dataChannelStateChanged();
    }

    dataChannelStateChanged() {
        console.log(this); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
setupPeerConnection() {
    this.dataChannel.onopen = this.dataChannelStateChanged.bind(this);
}
```

`bind` creates a copy of a function with the specified object set as `this`.